# Simplified Chinese characters showing as question marks in ios push notification

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, okhttp

Our push server sends pushes via GCM to both android and iOS (via APNS).  It all works fine most of the time.  However, some character sets (such as simplified chinese) appear as question marks when the iOS device unpacks the userInfo (and also visually, they are question marks).

I confirmed that we are posting (via java/okhttp) to

https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

with charset=UTF-8

example payload

```
String example = "{
    \"to\":\"token1\",
    \"priority\":\"high\",
    \"content_available\":true,
    \"delay_while_idle\":true,
    \"time_to_live\":0,
    \"messageBody\":\"漢字\"
}";

Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .addHeader("Accept", MEDIA_TYPE_JSON.toString())
            .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + gcmApiKey)
            .url("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send")
            .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, example))
            .build();
```

Any advice?

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: "we are posting via"... How?

Comment: added an example @fge